# How to automatically parse String @RequestBody as json

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I have an endpoint which should read a string value as body.

```
@RestController
public class EndpointsController {
   @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "api/{myId}/name", consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
   public String updateName( @PathVariable( MY_ID ) String myId, @RequestBody String name) {

     //will be: "new name"
     //instead of : newname
     return myId;
   }
}
```

My problem is, that client will call this with "new name" which is correct IMHO but the server reads this with the quotes, because it does not handle the string as a json object. How can I tell Jackson to parse the string as well (same way than it does with Pojos)?

Comment: Your `@PathVariable` doesn't match what you have in the URL, by the way.

Comment: how'd you know? its a constant ;)

Comment: please add a json request example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using Jackson as your JSON parser, you can simply declare your parameter with the type [`TextNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/TextNode.html). This is the Jackson type representing JSON strings.

```
public String updateName(@PathVariable(MY_ID) String myId, @RequestBody TextNode name) {
```

You can then use its [`asText`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/TextNode.html#asText--) method to retrieve its text value.

Comment: thats it, thanks a lot! I hoped for an easy solution without changing the api

Comment: Our API is now broken. It doesn't make sense to modify all services as suggested. I will search for a global configuration solution and let you know.

Comment: @baraka Please clarify how your comment relates to this answer. What API? How is it broken? What services? When/where did I suggest modifying all of them? What global configuration? I really don't understand your comment.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm terribly sorry for not explaining - we had an API (RestController) that worked fine until a spring 1.4.1 boot upgrade we did.
Since than a few services that has a string parameter are now suddenly getting the string value with double qoutes - ""SomeString"" - so the value is "SomeString".
This obviously causes us troubles further in the code.
I have to admit we failed to resolve this by now and have already implemented your solution. 
Thnx anyway.

Comment: @baraka I had a very similar situation when upgrading a spring app that required a java upgrade from 1.6 to 1.8 and spring 3.0.4.RELEASE to 3.1.0.RELEASE. Since then, any requests being made to my controller whose methods accept `@RequestBody String` as the param, arrive in URL encoded format. I now have to manually decode them. Sounds like you used the above mentioned solution, but did you ever figure out why that started happening? Just because of a version upgrade?

Comment: @Andrew long time has passed but we recall it was just the version upgrade. We had no time to track the specific change-set :(
IMHO changing the behavior of an interface is the same as breaking the interface contract.

Comment: Thank you. How should I correctly represent "some_string" in JSON for TextNode?
If I send "some_string" I get Error: Unsupported Media Type

Comment: I get it. I should use @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) instead of  @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

Comment: Swagger generates for TextNode unintelligible Example Value:
{
  "nodeType": "ARRAY",
  "array": true,
  "null": true,
  "number": true,
  "boolean": true,
  "float": true,
  "short": true,
  "object": true,
  "double": true,
  "bigDecimal": true,
  "textual": true,
  "bigInteger": true,
  "int": true,
  "binary": true,
  "valueNode": true,
  "long": true,
  "pojo": true,
  "missingNode": true,
  "integralNumber": true,
  "containerNode": true,
  "floatingPointNumber": true
}
So it looks much easier to remove inverted commas in String type :)