# Thymeleaf form not returning json object

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

My Html page is not retrieving the payload in form of json object. Instead it is returning the string. Any help

HTML Code Snippet:

```
<form th:object="${case}" novalidate="true" data-model="case" action="/hcp/patient/details/insurance" method="POST">
```

Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = {"/hcp/patient/details/insurance"},
        produces = "application/json", method = {RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST})
final String updatePatientInsurance(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @RequestBody String payload, BindingResult bindingResult)
        throws InvalidFormException, Exception {...
```

Comment: Because `payload` is String?

Comment: It should be stringified Json. But the string is not in json format.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001725/how-to-automatically-parse-string-requestbody-as-json

Comment: The form is unable to trigger the ajax call, where it will convert as json.

Comment: So i have a ajax call for it, but rendering function is not triggering while i am accessing the tab with this form. This is what the issue I found. Looking forward to solve this. Will update once i am done. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly rendered the tab when accessing solved the issue.

P.S: The render function actually converts the payload to JSON object

```
formController.render(tabContent, url);
```